# how to get rid of the dotted border on drop down focus in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have tried everything from setting outline: none to -moz-outline-style: none;
and outline-color: #fff; i have even set border:0 but it still shows on focus

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select {
    -moz-outline-style: none;     
    outline-style: none;
    outline-width: 0px;
    outline-color: -moz-use-text-color;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Try picking out pieces until one works. `outline: 0` is the first one I'd try by itself and go from there.

Comment: Really frustrating ,Unfortunately none of them worked . This happens when i TAB through the input fields  and only in FF

Comment: Very strange. Try using `!important` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
outline:0;
```

to start with..